# blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin doesn't work when master CSS file is attached?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I have icncluded a https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin in my MVC 3 project. What is a very suprising, when in my `Layout.cshtml` file I have that line

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the `file dialog` does not show when I click on the `Browse for files` button. **And more, the same situation takes place even if that `Home.css` file is empty**

If I just remove that `<link .... />` declaration that plugin works fine. Can anyone explain to me why that kind of magic takes place here ??

Here's the full list of includings required by that plugin, maybe it'd be helpful

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css?cdv=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?cdv=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css?cdv=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css?cdv=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css?cdv=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Content/FileUpload/load-image.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/tmpl.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ip.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/locale.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/FileUpload/main.js?cdv=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Use firebug to debug your css issue. Otherwise, post a link to a demo of the problem.

Comment: there are many CSS errors caused by the `bootstrap.min.css` file

Comment: and they are the same as in the demo page

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

The purpose was, in my `Home.css` file was that line:

```
input[type="file"] { width: 285px; background: white; }
```

when I've removed it, the plugin started working properly. Gosh...